# How can I use underscore _.pick in my if efficiently

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can we minimise this code using underscore?

```
if (!_.isEmpty(nextprops.category.children)) {
    let subCategory = [];

    _.map(nextprops.category.children, (category, key) => {
        if (!_.isEmpty(category.children)) {
            _.map(category.children, (subCat, key) => {
                subCategory.push(subCat);
          })
        }
    });

    this.setState({categories: nextprops.category.children, subCategory: subCategory});
}
```

Comment: I think this belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Whats the question? What does "minimise" mean?

Comment: "Efficient" normally means "fast-running". I guess you mean "elegant"?

Comment: I just want to minimise the code as possible Means refactoring this.

Comment: you can remove the if condition as the map will not work on null or empty array of objects. I am also pasting an answer with working jsfiddle code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reduce the code on two methods. Check the console.log for all three outputs.
https://jsfiddle.net/d2xzuxsj/

```
var nextprops = {category:{children:[]}}

//your code
console.clear();
nextprops.category.children = [
                            {children:["subcat1"]}, {children:["subcat2"]}];
if (!_.isEmpty(nextprops.category.children)) {
    let subCategory = [];

    _.map(nextprops.category.children, (category, key) => {
        console.log(category)
        if (!_.isEmpty(category.children)) {
            _.each(category.children, (subCat, key) => {

                subCategory.push(subCat);
          })
        }
    });

 console.log(subCategory);
}

//Method 1
let subCategoryA = _.map(nextprops.category.children, function(category, key){
   return _.map(category, function(subcategory, key2){
        return subcategory
     })
})
subCategoryA = _.flatten(subCategoryA)
console.log(subCategoryA)


//Method 2
let subCategoryB = [];

_.each(nextprops.category.children, function(category, key){
    subCategoryB = _.flatten(_.union(subCategoryB, _.map(category, function(subcategory, key2){
            return subcategory
     }) ))
})

console.log(subCategoryB)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually it helps me.